# Deployment not in a domain - psexec.exe or powershell remoting

Tags: powershell, deployment, powershell-remoting, psexec

I am working on an automated deployment process for a web application. The deployment will need to:

- Deploy DB changes to database using sqlpackage.exe
- Deploy reporting services reports to the reports server using the web service
- Deploy web app to web server(s)
- Deploy fonts for reports
- among other things

The first two are reasonably straightforward to run from the web server, as the web service and db are contactable, and the tools to deploy run over the network.

From reading it appears that powershell remoting should be the way to go, and internally this would not be a problem. However when deploying to production, this will be being carried out in a datacentre, where the machines (2web, 1db) are not on a domain at all. I'd like to come up with a generic process that can run both internally and externally with the appropriate configuration. Powershell remoting, with machines not in a domain appears to require a fair bit of configuration using https etc., as NT credentials can't be validated.

Should I battle out configuring powershell remoting, or would configuring this to just use psexec to execute a powershell script directly on the remote machien, copying the deployment artifacts to a drop folder on the remote machine be the best way to go?

psexec seems to "just work". It appears powershell remoting comes with a lot more pain.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use psexec then? You can restrict it's role to just getting you on to the remote machine, and not let it infect your scripts. I have not attempted to get ps remoting working on a non-domain, but it general I have found it to be fairly high effort to get going. Psexec, as you say, can often be simpler.

Excuse the peddling, but the open source framework I helped build called PowerUp essentially does all this for your. It uses a model in which the powershell (well psake) scripts can move execution to another machine by calling a specific function. This can either be done with powershell remoting or psexec - you wouldn't need to change the script, it just requires a setting per environment to say which you would like to use.

Check other the sample at https://github.com/AffinityID/PowerUpSamples/tree/master/SimpleWebsite.

Hopefully that shows you enough, but if not let me know and we can go into more detail.